# How do I support multiple websites on the same server with hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtualhost, hapi.js

Let's say I want to host my 2 websites (cats.com and dogs.com) on the same server with a single IP address (i.e. with virtual hosts). I want to write them both with hapi.js and have them running as a single process.

The sites may have overlapping paths, for instance they might both have a `/about` page.

How could I implement this with hapi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice way of achieving that with hapi is by putting your different sites in to separate [plugins](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins) and using the `vhost` modifier when loading the plugin, ideally using [Glue](https://github.com/hapijs/glue).

Here's an example:

**sites/dogs.js**

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

    // Put all your routes for the site in here

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Dogs homepage');
        }
    });

    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = { name: 'dogs' };
```

**sites/cats.js**

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

    // Put all your routes for the site in here

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            reply('Cats homepage');
        }
    });

    next();
};

exports.register.attributes = { name: 'cats' };
```

**index.js**

```
const Glue = require('glue');
const Hoek = require('hoek');

const manifest = {
    connections: [{
        port: 4000,
    }],
    registrations: [
        {
            plugin: {
                register: './sites/cats'
            },
            options: {
                routes: {
                    vhost: 'cats.com'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            plugin: {
                register: './sites/dogs'
            },
            options: {
                routes: {
                    vhost: 'dogs.com'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};

const options = {
    relativeTo: __dirname
};

Glue.compose(manifest, options, (err, server) => {

    Hoek.assert(!err, err);
    server.start((err) => {

        Hoek.assert(!err, err);
        console.log('server started');
    });
});
```

You can then confirm that the routing works correctly with a couple of cURL commands:

```
$ curl -H "Host: cats.com" localhost:4000/
Cats homepage

$ curl -H "Host: dogs.com" localhost:4000/
Dogs homepage
```

A browser will set that Host header for you though so when you browse to http://cats.com or http://dogs.com hapi will serve you the correct content (provided your DNS is configured correctly).

Comment: How do I serve templates ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Hapi version >= 17, the details have changed slightly, though the idea is the same.

We will want to have a plugin for each site. Then, once we have each site extracted into a plugin (`cats` and `dogs` below), we can compose the separate configurations using `glue` and serve the site with `hapi`.

In the example below, the plugins will not know or care which domain they are being served on.

## The Code

#### Cats Plugin

This is the "server" that's meant to be used with `cats.com`. It returns the text `Hello Cats!` at the root path, `/`. In real life it would do something more useful, and you would likely have many more routes and handlers in a real project, but the idea remains the same.

```
// ./sites/cats.js
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'cats',
  version: '1.0.0',
  register: async function(server, options) {
    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      handler: (request, h) => {
        return 'Hello Cats!'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### Dogs Plugin

This is the server for the content appearing at `dogs.com`. It is exactly the same as the `cats` plugin, except it returns the text `Hello Dogs!`. Again, this is not a useful plugin, it is for illustration only.

```
// ./sites/dogs.js
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'dogs',
  version: '1.0.0',
  register: async function(server, options) {
    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      handler: (request, h) => {
        return 'Hello Dogs!'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

#### Main Server

This is where the `vhost` is specified, assigning plugins to hosts `cats.com` and `dogs.com`.

```
// ./server.js
const Hapi = require('hapi')
const Glue = require('glue')

const manifest = {
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0',
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080
  },
  register: {
    plugins: [
      {
        plugin: './sites/cats',
        routes: {
          vhost: 'cats.com'
        }
      },
      {
        plugin: './sites/dogs',
        routes: {
          vhost: 'dogs.com'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

const options = {
  relativeTo: __dirname
}

const startServer = async function () {
  try {
    const server = await Glue.compose(manifest, options)
    await server.start()
    console.log('Hapi days for Cats and for Dogs!')
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

startServer()
```

## The Result

### Accessing the different versions

#### Starting the Server

```
$ node server.js
Hapi days for Cats and for Dogs!
```

#### Sampling Server Output

```
$ curl -H "Host: cats.com" localhost:8080/
Hello Cats!

$ curl -H "Host: dogs.com" localhost:8080/
Hello Dogs!

$ curl localhost:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

$ curl -H "Host: platypus.com" localhost:8080/
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```

Note that there are no routes for the default host, so not specifying a host will result in a `404` being returned.

Comment: Thanks for updating this